# Which renders first child or parent in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i am beginner in reactjs,and trying to understand concept like what and how the parent and child renders in reactjs

from research i found that react renders the child first and then parent,but i could not able to get the valid answer how and why? and what happen if child fails to render,i guess in react 16 there is a lifecycle called componentDidCatch that handles if child fails to render,so what was there before react 16 and how we handle those scenario

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `componentDidMount` fires you can do DOM manipulation so it makes sense that parent only receives it after children are mounted. That said you can use `componentWillMount` which fires in the opposite direction, parents first.

If that is clear this is how you wrap error catching in React 16.x:

**React 16.x Error Handling Example**

```js
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // Display fallback UI
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    logErrorToMyService(error, info);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

```js
<ErrorBoundary>
  <MyWidget />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Ref: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html

**REACT 15 Error Handling Example**

`unstable_handleError()` is a function for all components which is called when render or children render an error.

```js
unstable_handleError: function(){
  this.setState({error: "oops"})
}
```

```js
class Boundary extends React.Component {
      ...
      unstable_handleError() {
        logErrorSoYouCanFixTheThing()
        this.setState({error: true});
      }
      render() {
        if (this.state.error){
          return <SafeComponent/>
        } else {
          return <ComponentWithErrors/>
        }
      }
}
```

On mount there is no error, so it renders `<ComponentWithErrors/>`.

Assuming the `<ComponentWithErrors/>` throws an error, this component’s `unstable_handleError()` will be called and state will update to `error: true`.

When state updates, the `<SafeComponent/>` is instead rendered!

Answer (score 3):

This depends on definitions of 'child' and 'render'.

Child's `render` function is called first when a child is nested in parent's `render` because a parent needs to use the result of child's `render` in its own `render` function. In case a child is `children` prop it's also rendered first because a parent needs to receive it as `children` prop.

In this case a 'child' is nested element in parent `render`, a child is rendered and mounted first, error boundary in `Parent` will be able to catch errors from `Child`:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  componentDidCatch() {}
  render = () => <div><Child/></div>;
}

const Grandparent = props => <Parent/>;
```

In this case a 'child' is `children` prop, a child is rendered first but isn't mounted because `children` isn't used, error boundary in `Parent` wouldn't be able to catch errors from `Child` because `Child` is actually rendered in `Grandparent`:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  componentDidCatch() {}
  render = () => <div/>;
}

const Grandparent = props => <Parent><Child/></Parent>;
```

In React 15, [`unstable_handleError` lifecycle hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#naming-changes-from-react-15) was used to create error boundary and handle errors in children. It was replaced with `componentDidCatch` in React 16.