# Is it safe to assume the initial ancestor useEffect will run after all descendants useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to track when the initial render of my app has finished. Is it safe to assume a `useEffect` in the root component will run after all descendant `useEffect` have run a first time?

This is just a basic example to make it clear:

```
const App = props => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("root");
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {/*...*/}
        </div>
    );
};
```

.

```
const DeepDescendant = props => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("descendant");
    }, []);

    return (
        <div />
    );
};
```

`descendant` and in the end `root`.

**Edit**:

For clarification: I am using ReactDOM.hydrate to use the HTML from the page which comes from PHP. Some of the Components (their rendered HTML) are not included in the initial HTML. I need to know when the first render finished so I can then include them. I was tracking this individually but I wanted to know if I could rely on a global variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which renders first child or parent in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52963657/which-renders-first-child-or-parent-in-reactjs)

Comment: @Nicholas I was not sure if leaving the question without any code, so I just wrote a basic example, but I'll improve it to make it more clear. In my tests it works as I expected but I wanted to make sure this will always be the case. Thanks

Comment: In most cases (as i know) the Parent will finish to render last hence it needs to know about its childs

Comment: @Nicholas, so I guess the answer is that it is safe, it will always happen that way? Thanks

Comment: Unless you render child as a prop. But if you put in the parent render or in your case in return func than yes.